# tiny slider react error ReferenceError: window is not defined Nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, tiny-slider

I'm using 'NextJs 13`to build a website, in my home I have a slider of my products and I use`tiny-slider-react` to create a slider.

I added `use client` in the first line of my `carousel.js` file;

carousel.js file code:

```
"use client";
import TinySlider from "tiny-slider-react";
import CarouselItem from "./carousel-item";
import "tiny-slider/dist/tiny-slider.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Carousel(props) {
  const [mount, setMount] = useState(false);
  const { children } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window === "object") {
      setMount(true);
    }
  }, [setMount, window]);

  const settings = {
    lazyload: true,
    nav: false,
    mouseDrag: true,
    loop: true,
    items: 1,
    gutter: 20,
    controls: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    autoplayButtonOutput: false,
    speed: 250,
    autoplayTimeout: 2500,
    responsive: {
      2048: {
        items: 10,
      },
      1920: {
        items: 4,
      },
      1728: {
        items: 4,
      },
      1440: {
        items: 4,
      },
      1280: {
        items: 4,
      },
      1194: {
        items: 4,
      },
      1114: {
        items: 4,
      },
      1180: {
        items: 4,
      },
      1104: {
        items: 4,
      },
      1024: {
        items: 4,
      },
      834: {
        items: 2,
      },
      820: {
        items: 2,
      },
      800: {
        items: 2,
      },
      768: {
        items: 2,
      },
    },
  };

  if (mount) {
    return (
      <TinySlider settings={settings} onInit={() => {}}>
        {props.data.map((item) => (
          <CarouselItem key={item.id} data={item} />
        ))}
      </TinySlider>
    );
  }
  return null;
}

export default Carousel;
```

but every time I reload the page I get this error:

- error node_modules\tiny-slider\dist\tiny-slider.js (5:0) @ eval
- error ReferenceError: window is not defined
- at **webpack_require**
  (F:\Projects\nexjs\decoz.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
  at **webpack_require** (F:\Projects\nexjs\decoz.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
  at **webpack_require** (F:\Projects\nexjs\decoz.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
  at eval (./components/theme/home/carousel/carousel.js:7:75)

and I can't run 'npm run build` too, it gets this error:

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules

- info Linting and checking the validity of types
- info Collecting page data
  [    ] - info Generating static pages (0/4)ReferenceError: window is not defined
  at 1107 (F:\Projects\nexjs\decoz.next\server\chunks\738.js:10552:13)
  at **webpack_require** (F:\Projects\nexjs\decoz.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
  at 6088 (F:\Projects\nexjs\decoz.next\server\chunks\738.js:10212:19)
  at **webpack_require** (F:\Projects\nexjs\decoz.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
  at 7086 (F:\Projects\nexjs\decoz.next\server\chunks\738.js:10478:40)
  at **webpack_require** (F:\Projects\nexjs\decoz.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)

How to avoid this error?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "eslint": "8.40.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.1",
    "next": "13.4.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tiny-slider-react": "^0.5.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: I use `console.log(typeof window)` and it retruns object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `window` as a dependency of your `useEffect` hook. First of all, it is unnecessary. Second, it causes your error when Next tries to render your component on the server.

You can resolve this error by rewriting your effect as follows.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setMount(true);
}, []);
```

**UPDATE:** Another issue here is that `tiny-slider-react` is not compatible with SSR as it's referencing `window` object directly. You can resolve this error by dynamically importing `tiny-slider-react`.

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const TinySlider = dynamic(() => import("tiny-slider-react"));
```

Comment: I do this but still got same error

Comment: Please see my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same issue and managed to resolve with the following additional changes to Igor Danchenko's dynamic import solution.

First is a disabling server-side rendering for the plugin by adding the following parameter to the dynamic import:

```
const TinySlider = dynamic(() => import("tiny-slider-react"), {
    ssr: false,
});
```

and secondly toggling `reactStrictMode: false` in `next.config.js`.

If you leave strict mode set to `true` then it appears the plugin will fail while in dev environment, but will render correctly when running in prod.